# Number of weights to be learnt in the encoder decoder attention in the transformer model

Tags: neural-networks, transformers, machine-translation

I have a doubt about the number of weights to be learned in the encoder-decoder attention layer in the transformer model (attention is all you need). Some blogs articles say the $K$ and $V$ (key and value) matrices come from the memory (encoder output). This confused me. But If I'm right there should be:

- 8 matrices $W_K$
- 8 matrices $W_V$
- 8 matrices $W_Q$
- 1 matrix $W_O$

Right?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are right that these are the parameters that *conceptually* belong to the encoder-decoder attention (sometimes called cross-attention).

The *implementation* can be different. What your goal is fast inference, you can pre-compute the keys and the values for each head because they only depend on the encoder output and do not change during decoding. For each decoded token, there is only one query vector (disregarding beam search and batching) which is compared with constant precomputed keys and values.